# Edit properties of OneNote Notebook in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, onenote

I have a sharepoint which holds amongst other documents a OneNote Notebook.

Unfortunately I cannot edit any properties/columns except the name of the notebook. Accessing this folder with a file explorer will show this collection as a folder containing further folders and OneNote files.

When accessing the collection via the DataSheet view, it says that the corresponding cells are read-only.

This problem is mentioned in the last part 'The final touch' of the following article:
https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/OneNote-and-Metadata-in-SharePoint-Add-a-Notebook-to-a-Library-Part-4-of-5.aspx
Furthermore a solution shall be discussed in part 5 of 5 of the article. Unfortunately part 5 was never published :-(

Recreating this OneNote Notebook is no option for me as it has grown over several years right now and an automated synchronisation has been set up which I fear to disturb/destroy when recreating it.

Can you please help me out? What to do to edit the properties of this collection.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution.

The key to success is to handle a notebook like a folder. Keeping this in mind this is your solution:
http://www.sharepoint-guru.com/2007/06/adding-metadata-to-folder.html